# Make to cmake conversion include directives

Tags: cmake, gnu-make

I am working to convert a project that was previously built with make into cmake. The project is a plugin to a larger framework which makes liberal use of `include` statements e.g.

```
MY_VARIABLE       := no
MY_OTHER_VARIABLE := yes

include $(FRAMEWORK_DIR)/some_makefile.mk
```

I would convert the variables as

```
set(MY_VARIABLE       no )
set(MY_OTHER_VARIABLE yes)
```

but I don't know what to do with the `include` statement.

Because I am not responsible for the full project and these files could change with each release, I would rather not replace each one with a `CMakeLists.txt` as suggested in the cmake documentation. Is there some way to interface with these calls from cmake?

Comment: No,  CMake files cannot include makefiles.

Comment: @MadScientist okay, that's a shame. So is the best way of dealing with this using configure_file with the existing makefile and then adding it as a custom target or something like that?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want to do.  What the `make` `include` directive does is simply pretend that the content of the included file is cut and pasted into the including file.  That is, it's no different to make than if you did that cut and paste operation.  So obviously, if CMake can't parse the "outer" makefile it also can't parse the included makefile, since they're just the same thing.  If you convert the outer makefile to cmake you have to convert the included makefile to cmake as well since it's all just one big file.

Comment: I think that all makes sense to me. Given that a direct conversion of make to cmake isn't possible in this case, I want to use cmake to configure my existing makefile (set variables, etc.) and then have cmake execute make on the file. I believe I can approach this problem by using `add_custom_target`.

Comment: Yes, you will want to do something like that.

Comment: Why don't you think of it as a "3rd party" framework and include it into the CMake build system using `externalproject_add`?